# VBA excel : Copy Entire Row and paste above multiple times based on specific cell value. Then perform same task for next rows below

Tags: excel, vba, loops, row, copy-paste

Need packing list details by each carton. If a row have details which same for 4 cartons, need to copy & paste same raw 3 times above.

If H Column have 4, then I am using below VBA to command to type in 3. And same row copy and paste 3 times below.

But I want automate this process. So I don't have type in how many times need to be copy and paste for each row. I am newbie, new help will be appreciated.

```
Sub copy_paste2()

    Dim i As Integer

     

    i = Application.InputBox("How many copies?", Type:=1)

     

    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Resize(i).EntireRow.Insert

    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Resize(i).EntireRow.Value = ActiveCell.EntireRow.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to post your data as **text** which can be copy/pasted.  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Your question is not clear. And your screenshot does NOT show the same row being duplicated.  In particular, columns H & I are NOT duplicated. All other entries are exactly the same in all cells.  You will need to provide a lot more detail, and also show what you have tried to solve the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Hi @Ron, I need to figure out how to post my file. Thanks for pointing out for not posting image.

Answer (score 0):

Scan up the sheet so inserting rows does not affect the row iterator.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copy_paste2()

    Const COL_QU = "H"
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, n As Long, q
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_QU).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            'quantity
            q = .Cells(r, COL_QU)
            If Len(q) > 0 And IsNumeric(q) Then
                If q > 1 Then
                    .Rows(r).Copy
                    .Rows(r).Resize(q - 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
                    n = n + q - 1
                End If
            End If
        Next      
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
   
    MsgBox n & " rows inserted", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @peter, Its works perfectly. Also if you can advise how to learn these functions. that would be really helpful.

Comment: @Mohammad I would start by reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office)